# How to ignores labels in chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I'm new to chart.js and have the wall a bit with this:

```js
    <script>
      window.onload = function ()
      {

        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'line',
          data: {
//            labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
            datasets: [{
              label: 'Test graph',
              data: [100,200,30,700,40,500]
            }]
          },
          options: {

            scales: {
              xAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                      display: false //this will remove only the label
                  }
              }]
            }
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
```

It simple won't render unless I include the "labels" for the x-axis. Which I don't need so would like to just disable.

Any clues as to how to configure chart.js to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Chart.js needs a data point on the X and y axis to match data against, simplest work around you can use is to just provide an labels array with empty strings for the amount of data points you have

Comment: Thank you for the idea and - yes, that would work ofcourse. The plan though was to avoid the "labels" section all together since the dataset are generated and of variable size.

Comment: You can do some hacky things where you provide the data in object format like so `{x: xVal, y: yVal}` and then for the xVals you need unique things, then you can use the label tick callback to hide them by returning an empty string: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats